# How to make strings equal?

Tags: c++

In this a and "v1" does not come out to be equal...although the content is same..can someone help in suggesting a way such that a comes out to be equal to "v1"

```
int main()
{
    stringstream s;
    string a;
    char *c="v1";
    s<<c;
    a=s.str();
    cout<<a;
    int i=strcmp(a, "v1");
    cout<<"i="<<i;
}
```

On comparing a and "v1" do not come out to be equal...please suggest some way such that i may make a to be equal to "v1"...the end goal is to make a to be equal to "v1".

Comment: What does the program output?

Comment: `strcmp(a, "v1")` actually compiles?

Comment: `char *c="v1";` should be `const char *c="v1";`

Comment: I see no `strcmp` here, but I've added one to my answer.

Comment: @user1355603: You've edited your question to get rid of the strcmp, which completely changes the nature of your question and invalidates several of the answers you've now received.  Please don't do that.  By all means edit your post to add clarifications, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Because `strcmp` returns 0 when the inputs match.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)

(Incidentally, I assume that your actual code is `strcmp(a.c_str(), "v1")`, because otherwise it wouldn't have compiled.)

Comment: That i know...but i want string a to be equal to "v1"....my end goal is to somehow make a to be equal to v1

Comment: @user1355603: See e.g. http://ideone.com/RnYI5.  If that is not what you expect, please clarify!

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` requires a `char *`, where as `a` is of type `std::string`.

The `std::string` class provides a method that returns a format compatible with `strcmp`.
Try: `int i = strcmp(a.c_str(), "v1");`

Answer (score 0):

They *are* the same, at least lexically.  Note that `strcmp` returns `0` when the strings are the same, which is not the same as `true`.

```
int main()
{
    stringstream s;
    string a;
    const char *c="v1";
    s<<c;
    a=s.str();
    cout << a << "\t" << c;
    cout << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << (a == c) << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << (!strcmp(c, a.c_str())) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
v1      v1
true
true
```